# How can split a string with two conditions?

Tags: haskell

So basically I want to split my string with two conditions , when have a empty space or a diferent letter from the next one.

An example:

if I have this string ,`"AAA ADDD DD"`, I want to split to this, `["AAA","A","DDD","DD"]`

So I made this code:

```
sliceIt :: String -> [String]
sliceIt xs = words xs
```

But it only splits the inicial string when an empty space exists.
How can I also split when a caracter is next to a diferent one?
Can this problem be solve easier with recursion?

Comment: use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` but have a special case where space is ignored.

Answer (score 5):

So you want to split by `words` and then `group` equal elements in each split. You have the functions for doing so,

```
import Data.List

sliceIt :: String -> [String]
sliceIt s = concatMap group $ words s  

sliceItPointFree = concatMap group . words -- Point free notation. Same but cooler
```

Answer (score 2):

```
split :: String -> [String]
split [] = []
split (' ':xs) = split xs
split (x:xs) = (takeWhile (== x) (x:xs)) : (split $ dropWhile (== x) (x:xs))
```

So this is a recursive definition where there are 2 cases:

1. If head is a space then ignore it.
2. Otherwise, take as many of the same characters as you can, then call the function on the remaining part of the string.

Comment: Instead of writing `x:xs` twice in the body of your last equation, you could simplify to: `split (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (== x) xs) : (split $ dropWhile (== x) xs)`

Comment: span can be used in last line to simplify things. let (a,b) = span (== x) (x:xs)    in a:(split b)